# How can I print the List of WebElements in Selenium Drag & Drop code?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, arraylist, drag-and-drop

I need little hepl with the Selenium Drag & Drop code. where List of Element are not getting print
please help here codes give below :

```
package com;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import java.util.List;

public class DragDrop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html");

    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='box3']"));
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='box106']"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.dragAndDrop(from, to).perform();
    
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Capitals]"));
    for (WebElement items : options) {
        System.out.println(items.getText());
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }
    driver.close();
```

`

I tried to perform drag n drop function with List of Webelements.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, just change the below XPath expression:

```
//div[@id='Capitals]
```

To:

```
//div[@id='capitals']
```

I ran your code as it is by just changing the XPath expression as above, and here is the result on my console:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Capitals
Oslo
Stockholm
Washington
Copenhagen
Seoul
Rome
Madrid
****************************************
```

**UPDATE:** Second issue is that you will notice **Washington** being printed although it was dragged and dropped out of the capitals list. For this, your script needs to wait for few milli-seconds after drag and drop of Washington. You can use `Thread.sleep(2000)`, this code will put thread on sleep for 2 seconds. See below:

```
builder.dragAndDrop(from, to).perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='capitals']"));
```